# Linq To Entity - Filter Relational Data Problem

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have 2 tables.
Table 1 and Table 2. They have one to many relation. I'm trying to do a query like below. It works fine with finding the result. I mean if it cannot find any result according to the params i got null value as usual. However it brings all Table 2 results all the time in Table 1 class and I do want to get only Table 2 results according to the query.

```
dc.Table1s.SingleOrDefault(t1 => t1.SearchField1 == param1 
                           && t1.Table2s.Any(t2 => t2.SearchField2 == param2 
                                          && t2.SearchField3 == param3));
```

I do want the result as Table1 class and filtered with Table1.Table2s. Is it possible???

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the how you want the relationship between the two tables to be used.

For instance, if Table 2 has a reference to Table 1, and Table 1 has a collection of table 2:

```
var result = (from t1 in Table1s
             from t2 in t1.Table2s // this leverages the relationship
             where t1.sf1 == p1 
                   && t2.sf2 = p2
                   && t2.sf3 == p3
             select t1).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above will join the two using your relationship and give you all t1's that match the criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it still does not filter t1.Table2s at the result. I forgot to say that i'm using LazyLoading. May it be the reason?

Comment: Possibly - step through the code and before you call the linq query check to see if t1.Table2s has any results.

Comment: I have no problem with the query. If 3 criteria does not match i do not have result at all. So I'm pretty sure that query is working. The only reason when I get Table1 back from query and when i check Table1.Table2s, I saw 2 records not one. In LinqToSQL i have no problem like that. But i guess the reason is LazyLoading. It overrides the query when turning back the result...